# Laravel Select Input not showing on Request

Tags: laravel, forms, materialize, laravel-5.8

I have a form submitting to a controller but the controller not reading my Select Input on my request

below is the code that i have tried. i also try adding another input but the select is still not showing, i add a disabled, selected attributes but still not showing.

```
<form action="{{route('mycontroller.update',$model)}}" method="POST">
    @method('PATCH')
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="category" id="category">
    <select name="level" id="level">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

this is my controller

```
public function update(Model $model)
{
    dd(request()->all());
}
```

my model class

```
 protected $guarded = [];
```

this is my output

```
array:3 [▼
  "category" => "sdasdad"
  "_method" => "PATCH"
  "_token" => "some random characters"
]
```

this is my route

```
Route::resource('mycontroller', 'MyController');
```

Comment: did you add 'level' to $fillable property of your model class?

Comment: i got this on my model protected $guarded = []; i edit my post

Comment: it means that all of your columns are fillable, and can be updated during `update()` method. so it's not the problem. let me think about it

Comment: try this `request()->get('level', null);` I think you can't get the value, because nothing is selected.

Comment: @AmirRezaM75 i have try that and i get a null and im selecting either 1, 2 or 3 on my select

Answer (score 0):

In the controller

```
public function update(Model $model,Request $request)
{
   dd(request()->all());
}
```

you are not catching the requested data so just try this....

Answer (score 0):

I try to resolve my issue, im sorry i did not mention that i am using materializecss but i tagged it.

i replace my default select box **from**

```
 <select name="level" id="level">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

**to**

```
  <div class="">
    <label>Select priority level</label>
    <select class="browser-default" name="level" id="level">
       <option value="1" selected>One</option>
       <option value="2">Two</option>
       <option value="3">Three</option>
   </select>
  </div>
```

which now show the output of

```
    array:4 [▼
  "category" => "Testing"
  "level" => "2"
  "_method" => "PATCH"
  "_token" => "random token here"
]
```